# Using Atom like Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, atom-editor

I'm trying to do data analysis with the Atom editor, but the data size is too big so it takes a long time to load it all at once.
Is there any way to keep using that data once instead of loading it every time i run it in Atom?
I want use it like Jupyter.

Comment: you would have to run code in Python shell to keep it - and you would have to keep the same Python shell open all time. But even Python shell is not so useful as Jupyter. Better use Jupyter or tool which can run Jupyter.

Comment: Have you tried Hydrogen in Atom?

Answer (score 0):

Loading data files is limited by the speed of your storage. If you don't have an SSD, then upgrading to an SSD will help. If you have an SSD then you might be better off breaking the data up into smaller chunks, testing on 1 or 2 chunks, then using the full data set for analysis once you are confident with your code.

Another option would be to use cloud computing with SSD storage attached. Google Datalab is a Jupyter notebook environment that runs on GCP. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/) for specifics.